# Direction of magnetic field lines around a conducting wire

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, conductors

By way of the first uploaded picture I was taught that magnetic field-lines around a long conducting wire with a current are shaped like concentric circles around the wire. However, a few pages further down I am told in relation to the second picture that the magnetic field of the top wire is directed "into the page", perpendicular to the bottom wire.

I am confused… Could somebody help out?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The $F$ in the second diagram shows the **force** not the field. That is, the diagram shows the force between two wires due to the current flowing in them.

Comment: Do you mean that F2 is the result of the element of B1 that is directed "into the page"?

Comment: Yes. The force is at right angles to the direction of the magnetic field and the current. See [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force).

Answer (score 1):

> the magnetic field of the top wire is directed "into the page", perpendicular to the bottom wire.
>
> [image]

Yep, that is correct: it is consistent with your first figure and it is a correct application of the principle. This is hard to draw, but maybe this will make it clearer?

> [image]

Note that in this diagram the arrows marked $\mathbf F_i$ are forces (basically, $\mathbf F_2$ is the cross product of the magnetic field produced by $I_1$ and the current in $I_2$, and vice versa) and they are *not* the magnetic field that the text talks about.